# UDP Broadcast receive - Bind to several NIC's

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, broadcast

I am writing a program for Linux that should receive UDP broadcast packets from the specified port on any of the network interfaces that exist in the system.

However, if the system has multiple network interfaces of the same subnet address, the packets are accepted only by the first interface.

For example, if eth0 has 192.168.225.107 and eth1 has 192.168.225.108, packets accepted only from eth0.

NIC's are attached to different physical networks. According to the tcpdump, the packets are present in both networks.

Code (error checking skipped):

```
sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (void *) &on, sizeof(on));
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (void *) &s, sizeof(s));
bzero(&serv_addr_ip, sizeof(serv_addr_ip));
serv_addr_ip.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr_ip.sin_port = htons(port);
serv_addr_ip.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serv_addr = (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr_ip;
addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
bind(sock, serv_addr, addr_len);

while (1) {
    if ((chars = recvfrom(sock, var.buf, MSG_MAX, 0, serv_addr, &addr_len)) < 0) {
        ...
    }
...
}
```

Comment: If eth0 and eth1 are in the same subnet, doesn't that mean that you would get each broadcast packet twice? Might that be the reason why it is filtered out and only delivered to one adapter?

Comment: Here is a small trick. NIC addresses belong to the same subnet, but they are physically connected to different networks, which has different packets.

Comment: Did you try having eth0 configured for a different subnet? Did you try if eth1 works when eth0 is down?

Comment: You can't bind to several NICs. You can bind to INADDR_ANY, as you are doing. So what's your question?

Comment: Yes, then I down eth0, packets from eth1 is OK. My question is: why, although I use the INADDR_ANY, I see packets only from the address, which is assigned to the first network card.

Comment: Sorry to drag up an old question, but did you ever get a solution to this? I've got pretty much the same problem - multiple NICs, need to receive UDP broadcast messages on all of them. If I bind to INADDR_ANY I only get broadcast messages from the first NIC, and in my case eth0 and eth1 are two completely separate physical networks, usually with completely different subnet addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have two NICs, connected to two physical networks (i.e. network cables, hubs), with each having a separate IP address from the same subnet address range?

The short answer is that your network configuration is wrong. If they really are separate physical networks, then they should have different subnet addresses. It depends on what you mean with separate physical networks, separate hardware? You can NOT have two separate subnets with the same subnet address. Thats why I am saying your network configuration is wrong.

However, The impression I get is that you are trying to bridge the two networks, so that the two NICs belong to the same subnet (not separate). Well, then you should bridge them. You bridge the two NICs together and assign ONE IP address to the bridge. Then you will be able to receive your packets on both NICs.

In linux:

```
brctl addbr br0
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 down
ifconfig eth1 0.0.0.0 down
brctl addif br0 eth0
brctl addif br0 eth1
ifconfig eth0 up
ifconfig eth1 up
ifconfig br0 up
ifconfig br0 192.168.225.107 (or 192.168.225.108, whatever you prefer)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great idea. It works on the test machine, but unfortunately I can't change the network configuration on the target platform.